# Отсутствие перевода причины отклонения тревоги на странице тревог

Tags: дефект, статус-завершено, локализация

При переходе на страницу личных тревог у отклоненной тревоги отображается пояснение на английском языке:

> [image: What is Flagging?]

Comment: Проверьте, исправилось ли.

Comment: @alexolut да, обновилось.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Перевод был сделан, но не утверждён. После небольшой модификации будет выглядеть так:

> Использование стандартных тревог помогает нам приоритизировать проблемы и решать их быстрее. Пожалуйста, ознакомьтесь со списком стандартных тревог: смотрите «Что такое тревоги?»

Будет на сайте после подкачки Transifex и пересборки движка до версии `> 2017.12.4.28008`.

Comment: А не приоритИзировать ли?

Comment: @Kazantsev с этим разберемся ;)

Comment: лучше: разделять проблемы по приоритетам

Comment: или устанавливать приоритеты проблем